# Citing with the short title of a book

Tags: macros, citing

I was wondering how I could cite the short title of a book. For instance:

```
@book{Blackstone59, 
   Address = {London}, 
   Author = {Blackstone, William}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-03-15 11:58:40 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-03-15 11:59:24 +0000}, 
   Publisher = {Cavendish Publishing}, 
   Title = {{Commentaries on the Laws of England}}, 
Shorttitle = {{Commentaries}},
   Volume = {1-4}, 
   Origdate = {1765-9}, 
   Year = {2001}}
```

Do I have to define the command myself? If so, how can I do that? I don't understand how you can define a command by yourself, e.g. `\citeshorttitle{Blackstone59}`.

Comment: Why don't you call it `@book{Commentaries, ...` and use `\cite{Commentaries}`. Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: Which citation tool do you use? bibtex or biblatex? Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: As the others said, more context and a MWE might help. But, perhaps `citefield` could do the job. Something as `\citefield{Blackstone59}{shorttitle}`.